OpenTK.Input.GamePad.GetState(0) has an wrong return
I'm using OpenTK in my multiply platform game. I witnessed some bug after I update my OpenTK from 3.0.0-pre to 3.3.3
I have this code in my game:
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                GamePadState state = OpenTK.Input.GamePad.GetState(i);
                if (state.IsConnected)
                {
                   //...
                }
            }

When OpenTK is 3.0.0-pre, 0 return false; 1 return  false; 2 return  false; 3 return  false
But when OpenTK is 3.3.3  0 return  true; 1 return  false; 2 return  false; 3 return  false
The bug is when i equals 0, OpenTK.Input.GamePad.GetState(i) will return true!
I can make sure that there is no one GamePad which is connected to my PC.
I tried disconnect my mouse or my earphone, but it didn't work.
I cannot find any of the bug on the Internet.
